# Running VMware Workstation Pro 17 on Ubuntu 23.10 and getting I/O and memory errors that are causing Windows 10 (guest) to crash

Tags: vmware, 23.10

Here are the specs of my PC:

- Asus Prime B350-Plus
- Ryzen 7 5700X 3.4Ghz
- DDR 3200 32GB

Here's an excerpt from the vmware.log file showing errors that I believe are causing my Windows 10 VM to crash:

> ```
> 2023-12-25T06:07:34.080Z In(05) mks CoreDump error: Read, page 0xa00 (0x1b1416) Bad address
> 2023-12-25T06:07:34.080Z In(05) mks CoreDump error: Read, page 0xa01 (0x1305a5) Bad address
>
> 2023-12-25T06:07:34.380Z In(05) mks CoreDump error: Read, page 0xa00 (0x2de4ee) Bad address
> 2023-12-25T06:07:34.380Z In(05) mks CoreDump error: Read, page 0xa01 (0x1305a5) Bad address
>
> 2023-12-25T06:07:34.677Z In(05) mks CoreDump error: Read, page 0xa00 (0x22fa6f) Bad address
> 2023-12-25T06:07:34.677Z In(05) mks CoreDump error: Read, page 0xa01 (0x1305a5) Bad address
>
> 2023-12-25T06:07:36.117Z In(05)+ mks XINFO: IO fatal error.
>
> 2023-12-25T06:07:36.118Z In(05) mks SOCKET 6 (156) recv detected remote shutdown
> ```